# Postfix 'too many errors' after many RSET commands

Tags: postfix, smtp

I have a client who is complaining that their invoice emails are not all being sent out correctly. As far as I'm aware their invoicing software is designed to send emails directly.

Looking at a packet capture of a session, the client seems to be badly developed and is doing the following strange process -

```
-> MAIL FROM: <sender>
<- OK
-> RCPT TO: <customer>
<- OK
-> RSET
```

It does this for every individual email, then goes through again from the start, this time sending a full `MAIL/RCPT/DATA` set of commands.

```
-> MAIL FROM: <sender>
<- OK
-> RCPT TO: <customer>
<- OK
-> DATA
<- 354 OK..
-> (the email)
-> .
<- OK Queued
-> MAIL FROM: <sender>
... etc ...
```

The thing that interests me is that this works for a small number of recipients. However, the reason so many of their emails are going missing is because if the recipient list is too big, Postfix appears to end the connection during that first `MAIL/RCPT/RSET` stage for `too many errors`. This seems to happen after about 100 or so recipients.

```
RSET
250 2.0.0 Ok
MAIL FROM: <sender>
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: <customer>
250 2.1.5 Ok
RSET
250 2.0.0 Ok
MAIL FROM: <sender>
421 4.7.0 isp-smtp-server Error: too many errors
RSET
RSET
QUIT
```

Now I'm planning to reply and tell them it's an issue with the software. No idea if they have any channel to be able to get it fixed.

(EDIT: Apparently been told it goes via Outlook which has pushed me to consider  other systems possibly mangling this connection such as AV - https://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/rset-command-being-sent-after-authentication-smtp-server-successful)

Thing is, it doesn't actually report any errors at all during the session, so the client doesn't know it's accumulating errors. This also means I'm not 100% sure what the errors actually are (sending RSET without finishing a message?)

The logs don't show anything other than a normal connection followed by `too many errors`, which is why I had to resort to packet captures to find out what was happening.

Does anyone know what the specific error Postfix is counting, and what limit it is using to decide when it's too many? My soft error limit is the default `10` which is far lower than the amount of resets the client is doing before getting disconnected. I originally thought it might be that some recipients were being rejected, and that the number of rejected addresses eventually hit the error limit, but I don't see any rejections at all in the packet capture, and it ends on a `MAIL` command rather than `RCPT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure why this Outlook 2010 client is sending commands in this way, but I've managed to find out the answer to why Postfix suddenly decides to give up.

`RSET` is considered a junk command and the default `smtpd_junk_command_limit` is 100. Once this limit is reached, the `hard_error` count starts going up. When that hits 20 (default), totalling 120 overall, Postfix reports `too many errors`.